Role based access control in WSO2
I have an published an API say for example: https:/localhost:8243/{abc}/{xyz}.
I want to enable role based access to this API. For example there is a Role called Manager and a user callled abc_manager. I want that the user abc_manager using its password can only access this API. Is there any way possible for this using WSO2. If yes then please tell the steps.

One way to achieve this would be to secure your API using Oauth2 with JWT and define a dedicated scope (i.e. 'manager') to associate to the API.

This can be achieved by applying a scope to the API resource. The scope is bound to the role, and you can create a scope in the publisher portal[1] for the particular role and apply it to the resource you need to protect. You can use OAuth2[2] or Basic Auth[3] mechanisms to secure your API and achieve your use case.
Follow the steps below to achieve the use case:

Create a role and assign it to the particular user in the carbon management console.
Create a scope for the role and assign that scope to the API resource in the Publisher portal, then redeploy the API.
Invoke the API using Basic Auth or OAuth2

[1] https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/design/api-security/oauth2/oauth2-scopes/fine-grained-access-control-with-oauth-scopes/#local-scopes
[2] https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/design/api-security/oauth2/oauth2-scopes/fine-grained-access-control-with-oauth-scopes/
[3] https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/design/api-security/api-authentication/secure-apis-using-basic-authentication/#basic-authentication-with-scopes
